# how to manage the Y axis with custom prefabs in arcore

Tags: unity-game-engine, arcore

I have a strange problem in Unity (I never had it in Android).
I'm currently testing how the ARCore is working with unity, so I've run the basic demo that is delivered by Google. I didn't change even one line of code. The only difference is that I've set mu own prefab, simple cube. The problem that I have is related with the level on which the object is set. It always looks like it is set *below* the surface. For example if I find a surface on my chair and put the object there, than the object is set from floor, not from chair. I wonder what should I change to handle this.

The funny problem is that the same test on "clean" Android is not creating such problems.

Comment: Any update on this, I did face the same problem but in android, objects are shown floating above the floor?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have to check where the pivot point of your prefab is. I believe it has to be on the "floor" / at 0 on the Y axis.